# Solver for Jumble puzzle

Tags: python, beginner, performance, game, combinatorics

Here is my first attempt to solve [Jumble puzzle](http://www.arcamax.com/games/jumble/):

```
import argparse
from itertools import permutations


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Solver for Jumble')
parser.add_argument('jumbledwords', nargs='+',
                    help='One or more jumbled words')
argv = parser.parse_args()

# http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/wordlists/english/wordlist/wordsEn.txt
words = [line.rstrip() for line in open('wordsEn.txt')]
for jumbledword in argv.jumbledwords:
    perms = set([''.join(p) for p in permutations(jumbledword)])
    legalwords = [word for word in perms if word in words]
    # print(len(perms))
    print(jumbledword, legalwords)
```

Any suggestions for improvement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Close what you open**

```
words = [line.rstrip() for line in open('wordsEn.txt')]
```

Here you opened a file but you did not close it! In fact I suggest to use `with` that will handle closing automagically.

```
with open('wordsEn.txt') as f:
    words = [line.rstrip() for line in f.read()]
```

**Let the user change the file**

You should let the user input as an optional arg his own filename, I may have my own wordlist that is not called exactly: `'wordsEn.txt'`, the dafault file should be None (You read directly from the webpage).

**`set` built-in operations**

If you change the below line to be:

```
words = set([line.rstrip() for line in f.read().splitlines()])
```

You can then use `set intersection`:

```
legalwords = perms & words
```

To enhance both clarity and performance.

**Allowing long words**

The complexity of finding all the permutations of a word is `O(N!)`: for a mere 20 characters word that means `2.432 * 10**18` combinations, I suggest comparing the sorted words for better efficiency if you need to run the script with long words.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable inputs. FYI, 'wordsEn.txt' is already sorted and I think using list will maintain the order.

Comment: You are right that `set intersection` is better performance than `list`. I do not understand what you mean by _sorted words_ because there are no order in set. Could you expound more? I will post the revised code as a new answer.

Comment: @inyoot I mean an unsorted collection of sorted words.

Comment: could you give example, @Caridorc ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my revised code. I fixed the unclosed file problem. I use `set intersection` instead of `list`.

```
import argparse
from itertools import permutations


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Solver for Jumble')
parser.add_argument('jumbledwords', nargs='+',
                    help='One or more jumbled words')
argv = parser.parse_args()

# http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/wordlists/english/wordlist/wordsEn.txt
with open('wordsEn.txt') as f:
    words = {line.rstrip() for line in f}

for jumbledword in argv.jumbledwords:
    perms = set([''.join(p) for p in permutations(jumbledword)])
    legal_words = perms & words
    # print(len(perms))
    print(jumbledword, legal_words)
```

There is significant performance improvement by using `set intersection` instead of 'list'.

```
(list)$ time python jumble_puzzle.py nabando enegativ
nabando ['abandon']
enegativ ['negative']

real    1m5.735s
user    1m5.556s
sys     0m0.060s

(set)$ time python jumble_puzzle.py nabando enegativ
nabando {'abandon'}
enegativ {'negative'}

real    0m0.170s
user    0m0.153s
sys     0m0.016s
```